# Why was Prince Tommen absent during the trial by combat?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

After watching season 4 episode 8 of this amazing show, I suddenly noticed that one man was missing during the final part of the episode. It's Prince Tommen. But why?

It's clear why he was absent during the trial itself - he was not the judge, and he could have affected the jury by his mere presence.

But why would he miss the fight? It involves

> the fate of his elder brother and his own uncle.

Why on earth would he not go to the fight? The whole small council was present, so he could not be busy with state affairs at that moment.

Comment: Prince Tommen recused himself from the trial of Tyrion Lannister at the very beginning . The trial wasn't over until the end of Trial by Combat. So he could,should,would not attend the fight also

Comment: That is true for the trial itself. But for the combat that is not true, since no one expected that Tyrion would demand such thing. Besides, in combat Tommen could in no way influence both fighters, therefore it was absolutely safe for him to be present as an observer

Comment: The trial was for "King's Justice". In normal circumstance, King would head the panel of judges & give out the verdict & sentencing. But Tommen recused himself from this trial, so Hand of the King was delivering King's Justice in his stead. It would not be appropriate for the King, who recused himself, to sit through a Trial by Combat as a mere spectator. That was my point

Comment: Tommen is a child. No doubt children are not allowed at events which ends with people dying messily.

Comment: @TLP I'm sure Tommen and Myrcella were present for The Hand's Tournament in Season 1 and Joffery's Name Day Tournament in Season 2...

Comment: @CyanAngel Well, there is a big difference between a tournament and a trial by combat.

Comment: @TLP not really, both are based on the principle that a winner is declared when one party concedes or dies

Comment: @CyanAngel - No. In a tourney death is the exception. An unfortunate accident. Knights fighting in a tourney use blunted weapons and tourney lances that shatter on impact.

Comment: @system down we've clearly been watching different shows lol

Comment: @CyanAngel When have they ever fought to the death in a tourney in the show?

Comment: Fights to the death are rated PG-17, and Tommen is not old enough yet.

Comment: @CyanAngel [The death of Ser Hugh of the Vale](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/41519/2256) at the Tourney of the Hand was a deviation from normal, and most likely occurred only because Ser Gregor felt like killing someone. Like System Down says, they do not fight with real weapons.

Comment: @TLP they do not fight with the intent to kill*. The weapons, while stunted, are real. The blades may be dull and the lances brittle, but they'll still cut and pierce.

Comment: @TylerH No, the weapons do not cut, because they have no edge, and no, they do not pierce, because they have no point. So, no, sorry, but you are completely wrong. The weapons are not "real", they are "tourney" weapons, "tourney swords" and "tourney lances".

Comment: @SPIRiT_1984: “That is true for the trial itself. But for the combat that is not true, since no one expected that Tyrion would demand such thing.” The combat is part of the trial, hence the name “*Trial* by combat”. How does expectation make a difference?

Answer (score 11):

Tommen is absent in the books as well. Tyrion notes that:

> King Tommen was not in evidence; for that, at least, Tyrion was grateful.

According to the ASOS appendix, Tommen is a boy of eight years old. And for what it's worth he is described by everyone as a "sweet boy." Tywin, Cersei, etc must have decided it would not be appropriate to have him watch two men fight each other to the death, potentially condemning his uncle to death as well.