# Why did Gregor Clegane do that in Game of Thrones S8E5?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Why did Gregor *The Mountain* Clegane

> kill Qyburn and disobey the queen?

Ok, he wants to fight his brother, but that is not a reason for such an action. He is easily stronger than both of his allies, so he could have just ignored them.

Also, I am not quite sure, why he wants **that much** to fight his brother really.

Comment: #CleganeBowl #GetHype

Comment: Using extreme, brutal force regardless of whether it's needed or warranted sort of *defines* The Mountain. I suppose Zombie Mountain is even more mindless.

Comment: because he kinda forgot he was bewitched and brainwashed, AKA fanservice

Comment: “Ok, he wants to fight his brother, but that is not a reason for such an action.” Isn’t it? Why not? Jaime wanted to be there for his sister, despite having someone who loved him at Winterfell, and despite the almost-certain death from being by her side. Doing things for family is basically the entire foundation of the whole story.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Could be a reason for ignoring Cersei, but why kill Qyburn?

Comment: @TGar: because Qyburn was in his way. Ser Gregor merely pushed him out of the way. It's not Set Gregor's fault Qyburn's skull is so fragile!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite He picked him up by the throat and threw him into a pile of rubble; not *quite* the same as just pushing him out of the way.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: when the Mountain pushes someone out of the way, he does not use half-measures! He makes sure they get and stay out of the way!

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I don't think the Mountain understood, even when fully alive, the difference between "shoving someone away" and "destroying him/her".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## It's just a Gregor thing

I'll reiterate my point from [earlier](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/79701/21267), George R. R. Martin has written Gregor Clegane as a "murderous brute":

> He's a murderous brute, and really needs no reason to kill someone.
> <sup>*-[**So Spake Martin** http://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/Asshai.com_Interview_in_Barcelona](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Tournament#Tourney_of_the_Hand).*</sup>

Imagine how much more murderous and brutish he is once revived as an undead version of himself. GRRM has also said about those who survive death that:

> My characters who come back from death are worse for wear. In some ways, they're not even the same characters anymore. The body may be moving, but some aspect of the spirit is changed or transformed, and they've lost something. One of the characters who has come back repeatedly from death is Beric Dondarrion, The Lightning Lord. Each time he's revived he loses a little more of himself. He was sent on a mission before his first death. He was sent on a mission to do something, and it's like, that's what he's clinging to. He's forgetting other things, he's forgetting who he is, or where he lived. He's forgotten the woman who he was once supposed to marry. Bits of his humanity are lost every time he comes back from death; he remembers that mission. His flesh is falling away from him, but this one thing, this purpose that he had is part of what's animating him and bringing him back to death. I think you see echoes of that with some of the other characters who have come back from death.
> <sup>*-http://www.maximumfun.org/sound-young-america/george-r-r-martin-author-song-ice-and-fire-series-interview-sound-young-america#transcript*</sup>

This is echoed multiple times with Gregor, given how dead he was and how focused he was on his rage against his brother, Sandor.

You'll recall that this isn't the first time that he's disobeyed orders and protocol to go after Sandor, in Season 1 of *Game of Thrones* (and the related first book, A Song of Ice and Fire: A Game of Thrones), he attacks and nearly kills no other than Sandor Clegane, during the [tourney of the Hand](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Tournament#Tourney_of_the_Hand).

Their rivalry has been built up for a very long time, both in-universe, as well as out-of-universe.

Comment: +1 Great answer. As if (zombie) Gregor needed an excuse to engage in wanton violence.

Comment: It would be neat to also show how John Snow has changed as one of the "brought back from the dead" characters.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Lol, they couldn't remove a starbucks coffee cup from a scene, you want them to remember about Jon Snow's resurrection? Their continuity is not a strong point.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast It could be argued though, that since the last thing Jon Snow was focused on was protecting the realm against the Night King, and saving Winterfell at all cost, he sort of did become focused on that after resurrection. To the point where he dismisses his rightful claim to the Iron Throne.